# Android input box pre popluate input box

Tags: android, xml, apk

how do I prepopulate text (as user entered) into an input box in xml?

For example, I have a server box, how would I hard code text in there?
in the layout xml, it is set as
android:hint="server url"

I tried using android:text="@string/hostname" sfter adding to strings.xml in res values strings.xml:

```
<string name="host">http://example.com</string>
```

but that doesnt work. I need it to be hard coded in as if someone typed it.

Hint is just an overlay, but I need it entered in. What can I do? Id prefer only to use xmls

Here is my xml

```
<EditText 
android:textSize="15.0dip" 
android:textColor="@color/black" 
android:textColorHint="@color/white" 
android:id="@id/et_sever_url" 
android:background="@drawable/selector_login_fields" 
android:paddingLeft="20.0dip" 
android:paddingRight="20.0dip" 
android:focusable="true" 
android:nextFocusUp="@id/et_password" 
android:nextFocusDown="@id/bt_submit" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="50.0dip" 
android:layout_marginLeft="25.0dip" 
android:layout_marginTop="20.0dip" 
android:layout_marginRight="25.0dip" 
android:text="@string/host" 
android:maxLines="1" android:lines="1" 
android:layout_below="@id/et_password" 
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" 
android:inputType="text" 
android:textCursorDrawable="@null" 
android:fontFamily="sans-serif" />
```

Comment: "I need it to be hard coded in as if someone typed it" -- `android:text` *is* as if someone typed it, assuming that you are referring to an `EditText` widget. What do you see as the difference?

Comment: I would assume that text is suppose to be used in my case, but it still shows as a hint or overlay

Comment: ohI think i see what you mean

Comment: it is under editText, would this need to be changed?

Comment: `EditText` is the correct widget to use for text entry in an Android app.

Comment: i want to hard code the text "username" in so user doesnt need to type it

Comment: Use `<EditText android:text="username" ...>`, where `...` are your other attributes (height, width, ID, etc.).

Comment: android:text is correct. And if you want to disable editing, in your activity call EditText.setEnabled(false)

Comment: Its still showing as hint. Im not sure why. Ill keep digging thanks everyone!

Comment: I added xml to the original post.